# What happens at the intermediate pointer table when a process is forked? C fork function

Tags: c, unix, fork, file-descriptor

As you may know, the file descriptors in a process identifies a file operation (reading, writting...). When we make operations with these files we have to communicate with the OS since it's the one which manages files. With this purpose, the OS has a intermmediate pointer table in which for every single opened FD in every process, a entry is created. This table contains information (file pointer, type of operation...) about all the opened FDs. My question is, what happens in this table when a process is forked? My intuitive answer is that the entries of the table that belong to the forked process are duplicated at the table in order to have other intermediate pointers in the child process but I haven't found any info about this so I'd be glad to someone clarify this.

Thanks beforehand =)

Comment: There is no difference between parent and child, they basically are copies , except for the return value of the fork() call. [well: there are some extra *minor* differences , mostly involving locks and signals. See the man page for these]

Comment: I think that my question was misunderstood because I am not talking about the FDs table of the process but the table at the OS.

Comment: Please read some books (Bach, Stevens,...) There are per process tables and there is the system file table. It is all in the books.

Answer (score 1):

The table is duplicated. The duplication isn't just a `memcpy()` and outstanding IO only completes in the parent process. The child inherits all handles from the parent. The kernel file objects themselves are *not* duplicated but only their table references.

Comment: What do you mean by "the file handles...are not duplicated"?  If there is unflushed data in a FILE * buffer, it will eventually be printed from each process, which would mean the object is duplicated.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I read "file handles" as "file descriptors", and [duplicating a file descriptor has strictly-defined semantics](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) that don't apply to file descriptor inheritance across a `fork()`.  But other interpretations are possible...

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I sure didn't read it as C `FILE *` objects. The behavior of those across `fork()` is just ugly.

Comment: I guess my question really is, what is meant by  "file handle"?  There are `FILE *`'s, file descriptors, and file descriptions.  Is there a concrete definition of "file handle"?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: If OP comes back and says he wants to know about `FILE *` let me know and I'll write the answer for that.

Comment: But what do you mean by the expression "file handle"?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Ah I see it now. Made a fix.